# How to show negative entropy is a proper closed convex function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, convex-analysis, entropy

The negative entropy function is:
\begin{align*}
    f(x) = \begin{cases}
    \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \log(x_i), & x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}_{++}\\
    \infty, & \text{ otherwise}.
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}

I know how to show that this is a convex function (this is the easy part). Moreover, by Wikipedia, we see that a function is a proper convex function if $f(x) >-\infty$ for all $x$ and $f(x) <\infty$ for at least one $x$. The first condition $f(x) >-\infty$ can be seen by minimizing the terms $x_i \log(x_i)$ which gives $-1/e$ hence the summation is at least $-n/e > -\infty$.  The latter condition $f(x) < \infty$ is easy to see. Now I just want to conclude that this is also closed.

By Wikipedia, "A proper convex function is closed if and only if it is lower semi-continuous." So, should I just show $f(x)$ is lower semi-continuous? If yes, how?

Comment: This is not true as stated. In 1D, take a sequence $(x_k)$ of positive numbers that converges to $0$. Then $\infty=f(0)>\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_k)=0$.

Comment: @MaoWao Our understanding is $0 \log(0) =0 $. This is the main approach in optimization community to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Then your notation $\mathbb{R}^n_{++}$ is at least misleading. If you mean $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid x_i\geq 0\text{ for all }i\}$, then this is a closed subset and $f$ is clearly continuous on it, hence $f$ is l.s.c. on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @MaoWao thanks for your answer. How do you conclude it is `clearly' continuous?

Comment: @MaoWao I think it is clearly lower continuous, not continuous.